# EntityStreamSizeException Due to Request Content Size Limit Exceeded

Tags: ibm-cloud, cplex, docplex, watson-studio, docplexcloud

I'm using Watsons Machine Learning service to deploy Docplex model (Lite plan). I encountered an error related to model.tar.gz file size limit issue when making a request to the platform. The error message received is as follows:

> Exception has occurred: ApiRequestFailure
> Failure during scoring asyncronously.
> Status code: 413. The request content was malformed:
> EntityStreamSizeException: incoming entity size (32281635) exceeded size limit (10485760 bytes)! This may have been a parser limit (set via pekko.http.[server|client].parsing.max-content-length), a decoder limit (set via pekko.http.routing.decode-max-size), or a custom limit set with withSizeLimit.

To deploy the model I'm using [this example](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/4eb22192-eca4-4720-8b9b-d7606f189394/view?access_token=638d4a7461ea2901dd3ae8c85d61fbf2e53e913e4003762781169c568e4a3169&context=cpdaas)

The error occurred while executing:

```
solve_payload = {
    client.deployments.DecisionOptimizationMetaNames.SOLVE_PARAMETERS: {
        'oaas.logAttachmentName': 'log.txt',
        'oaas.logTailEnabled': 'true',
        'oaas.includeInputData': 'false',
        'oaas.resultsFormat': 'JSON'
    },
    client.deployments.DecisionOptimizationMetaNames.INPUT_DATA: [
        {
            "id": cplex_file,
            "content": getfileasdata("model.lp")
        }
    ],
    client.deployments.DecisionOptimizationMetaNames.OUTPUT_DATA: [
        {
            "id": ".*\.json"
        },
        {
            "id": ".*\.txt"
        }
    ]
}
job_details = client.deployments.create_job(deployment_uid, solve_payload)
```

The idea I got from IBM support to address this issue is by adjusting the `pekko.http.server.parsing.max-content-length` parameter to an `infinite` value. And as far as I understood, the problem is on the server side and not on mine. Or is that the limitation only for the Lite plan?